# Can't find the memory leak in C program

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am trying to write my first project in C and have some problems with the memory leak. I can't find the mistake, but I assume something's wrong with the do-while loop. The program compiles, but when I try to open it, I get a segmentation fault error. What am I doing wrong?

The file I am opening in my program is a .txt with the sequence of chars, for example: dvorndvl.

My aim is: I open the program with argument, it opens the file named argv[1] and writes the sequence of chars from the file to the array.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"file1.h"
#include"file2.h"

void bye(){
    puts("See you!");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char a[30];
    int i, x;

    printf("-----SOME TEXT-----");

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (f = NULL) {
        printf("User doesn't exist.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        do{
            a[i] = getc(f);
            i++;
        } while(a[i]!=EOF);

        char b[30];
        printf("Password? ");
        scanf("%c", b);

        if(strcmp(a,b) == 0){
            printf("\nHi, %s!\n", argv[1]);
            printf("What do you want to do?");
            printf("1. Turn the devices on/off. \n");
            printf("2. Change my password. \n");
            printf("3. -EXIT-\n");

            switch(x) {
                case 1:
                    devices(); break; //in file1
                case 2:
                    encrypt(argv[1]); break;//in file2
                case 3:
                    atexit(bye); break;
            }
        }
        else
            printf("Password is incorrect\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output are you currently seeing? Not sure if this helps but maybe initialize i = 0.

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger ?

Comment: Use `fgets` to read into `b`, it's a char array, not a char.

Comment: Initialized i=0, didn't help. 

I didn't use a debugger since I have no knowledge of programming, I'm just getting started and wanted to write something small. 

I corrected getc, but it also didn't help.

Comment: If you are on linux, you can run the program with gdb and once it segfaults write "up" and press enter, you'll be able to tell where it seg faulted

Comment: `"user doesn't exist"` is *not* a useful error message. Try  `f = fopen(argv[1], "r"); if (f == NULL) { perror(argv[1]); exit(1); }`

Comment: Not on linux, unfortunately windows user here. I am connecting to some server via SSH and can't install anything. Anything easy I can use in windows cmd?

Comment: are you actually passing command line arguments to the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advice to reverse the comparison and have (NULL == f) is both irrelevant and bad.

The real problem is that you are compiling your code wrong and that probably stems from using bad resources for learning.

I suspect you are using gcc and just passing the target file as an argument.

Instead, you should pass -Wall and possibly other flags, like this:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra crap.c 
crap.c: In function ‘main’:
crap.c:18:5: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
     if (f = NULL) {
     ^~
```

As you can see the compiler spots the unintended assignment no problem, you just have to ask it. It can also spot a myriad of other problems, which you know ask for with the aforementioned flag.

Also note how reversing the comparison does not help if 2 variables are at play, e.g. switching if (foo = bar) to if (bar = foo) does not help you whatsoever. On the other hand asking the compiler to warn you about problems catches the case.

If you are using a different compiler, it most certainly has a way to enable warnings. For the sake of argument, if you got one which cannot do basic analysis, stop using it.
I strongly advise you DON'T if (NULL == f) because that's against most commonly used style and as noted above it does not help with anything.

The code is still pretty buggy, beyond what the compiler can easily spot. I may get around to annotating it later.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 50 reputation to give you only a comment :( 
but
I guess a handler to *f is a issue. You don't check if 'f' is a NULL but you are assign f to NULL.

```
  if (f=NULL) {
     printf("User doesn't exist.\n");
     exit(1);
```

should be:

```
  if (f==NULL) {
         printf("User doesn't exist.\n");
         exit(1);
```

good practice is to always check if NULL is equal f :

```
   if (NULL == f) {
         printf("User doesn't exist.\n");
         exit(1);
```

in that case if you make mistake, program will not compile :)

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I spent nearly an hour to solve the issue and it was so simple I am actually ashamed right now. Have a nice day and thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2):

there are number or minor errors here
for first

`int i, x;` `i` doesnt have a value so you cant raise it with `i++`
also
`if (f = NULL) {` should be changed to `if (f == NULL) {`

`char a[30];` and `getc` are pretty risky you should use a temp string and `malloc`
an array to fit your needs and switch from `getc` to `fgetc`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are wrong here:

```
 if (f = NULL) {
```

You are changing `f` to be `NULL`, not testing it against `NULL`. Use `==`. To prevent this kind of error in the future, put the r-value on the left hand side, like so:

```
 NULL == f
```

Next:

```
char b[30];
scanf("%c", b);
```

If you were going to use `scanf` to read the string, you need to use `%s` format specifier, not `%c`, which is for single characters. I'd not use `scanf` at all though; use `fgets` instead because it's safer.

Comment: It's better to check end of file with `feof` and it is better to put zero in end of b, `b[i] = 0`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That "==" thing was so simple, yet I didn't notice it. Also, I deleted scanf and put fgets in my code. Once again, thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Exaequet you're welcome; if you found my answer to have solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the checkmark near the voting arrows!